# How to match current date with the database entries and retrieve it

Tags: mysql, perl, date

Suppose I have a MySQL table called birthday with dob as a column. dob has lot of dates in date time format. I have a perl variable `$test=current date`. My problem here is, how can I get the all the values present in the dob column that matches with the day and month of `$test`.

Let us assume, `$test='2013-05-28 00:00:00'` So, now I dont know how to write a query to select all the entries in MySQL table which matches the day and month of the `$test i.e 28 and 5 respectively`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `Month` and `Day` function inside `mysql` query like

```
select * from birthday where Day(dob) = Day('2013-05-28 00:00:00')
and Month(dob) = Month('2013-05-28 00:00:00');
```

Hope it works.

Comment: You don't need `Day('2013-05-28 00:00:00')`. Just use `28` instead. Same for `Month('2013-05-28 00:00:00')` -- use `5`.

Comment: in this problem @Vishu has a full `datetime` value,ok `Day('2013-05-28 00:00:00')` is just to extract `Day` from whole `Datetime`..